# The image doesn't show and I can't figure out why

Tags: javafx-8

I made a method for showing an image at mouse hover. The message from the system.out.println("success!!!"); is shown when I hover, but the image doesn't appear. Can anyone help me?

```
public void titleView() {

    Image img = new Image("Img\\titleSirius.png");

    ImageView title = new ImageView(img);
    title.setImage(img);
    title.setLayoutX(569);
    title.setLayoutY(146);
    title.fitHeightProperty().add(100);
    title.fitWidthProperty().add(100);
    title.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("success!!!");

 }
```

The folder 'Img' is in the src folder of my project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the ImageView object to your scene, e.g:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ShowImage extends Application
{ 
    public void titleView(Pane pane)
    {
        Image img = new Image("Img\\titleSirius.png");

        ImageView title = new ImageView(img);
        title.setImage(img);
        title.setLayoutX(569);
        title.setLayoutY(146);
        title.fitHeightProperty().add(100);
        title.fitWidthProperty().add(100);
        title.setVisible(true);

        pane.getChildren().add(title);

        System.out.println("success!!!");        
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        Pane root = new Pane();

        titleView(root);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 640, 480);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);               
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Question looks like it's supposed to trigger on 'mouse hover', so the pane probably needs an event listener, rather than making ImageView visible on startup. @nejinx

Comment: This works but in a total different pane i need something that will appear next to an image so i cant use this but thanks anyway i appreciate it.